# how can i pass custom function when sublassing from thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this code

```
class MyTh(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name,
                                  verbose=verbose)
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        return

    def run(self):
        logging.debug('running with %s and %s', self.args, self.kwargs)
        return

def my_func(): 
   print 'Everything OK'
```

when i do this

```
t1 = MyTh(name='Thread '+ str(i), target=myfunc, args=("test",), kwargs={'a':'A', 'b':'B'})
    t1.start()
```

my target function is not called at all. how can i make my thread call the default function given in target

Comment: Your basic set up works fine for me, except `target=myfunc` should be `target=my_func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding the `run()` method you mess up the standard `run()` and never call the target. What you need is to either not override the method or override it like so:

```
def run(self):
    logging.debug('running with %s and %s', self.args, self.kwargs)
    super(MyTh, self).run()
    return
```

This way the standard `Thread.run` is also called and `target` is executed.

Also you are not passing `args` and `kwargs` to the `Thread` constructor. You need to have:

```
threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name,
                              verbose=verbose, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

In order for them to be properly set. Then you can change your `my_func` to:

```
def my_func(arg1, a, b):
    print arg1, a, b
    print 'Everything OK'
```

Also, `MyTh`'s constructor and the call of `Thread.__init__` are unnecessary long. This is a lot shorter and readable:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.args = kwargs['args']
    self.kwargs = kwargs['kwargs']
```

Notice how the `args` and `kwargs` which you pass to the constructor are actually accessible as `kwargs['args']` and `kwargs['kwargs']`

Comment: that is working but my argument `test` is not accessible inside myfunction , how can i get that

Comment: @user192362127 Take a look at the the edit. There is also a suggestion on how to make your custom `MyTh` a bit more readable.